# Communicating to a process launched in the Terminal in UNIX through python

Tags: python, wxpython, subprocess

I am creating a GUI to facilitate some of the task in UNIX.
I would like to launch a process throught Terminal in UNIX. 
I used the module of

```
subprocess.Popen()
```

to launch the process.
The problem is that when i launch the process, the process demands the user, their password. 
I am thinking of creating a window to ask the user for their password.
How can i send the password typed in the window to the process launch in the Terminal?

here is the code:

```
password = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "What is your password?", 'Password')
    if password.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        response = password.GetValue()

        command = 'ssh -X pcalcul0 firefox http://qualnetsrv/intraqual//identification.aspx?ref=G0-1427'
        user_manual = subprocess.Popen(command, universal_newlines=True, 
                                       stdin=response,
                                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                                       stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                       shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [Pexpect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect) package to do this sort of thing. It has been detailed in other answers such as this one:

- [Sending a password over SSH or SCP with subprocess.Popen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166973/sending-a-password-over-ssh-or-scp-with-subprocess-popen)

Alternatively, you could just create some SSH keys so it automatically logs in.

The other way I know of is to use use [Paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko). Then you can use Python itself to do the SSH / SCP that you need.

- http://dtucker.co.uk/hack/ssh-for-python-in-search-of-api-perfection.html