# python popen with ssh doesn't capture the output

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, popen

I am trying to use popen to interact with ssh. But it seems like there is not way to redirect stdoutput

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/ssh","192.168.254.1", "user"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False, bufsize=10000)
out, err = proc.communicate()
```

When I run the script both the output and the err are empty, and the command line is showing

```
user@192.168.254.1's password:
```

what am I doing wrong? It has the exact same behavior when I set shell=True. Also before people tell me to use pexpect of the pxssh I have tried those, and they won't work for my application. I am running this script inside a daemon service and pexpect fundamentally handles the T100 and linux control codes/escape characters differently, and in certain reproducable instances looses part of the byte stream.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: `ssh` reads the password from the terminal, not stdin.

Comment: terminal as in directly from tty?

Comment: Yes, terminal == tty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending a password over SSH or SCP with subprocess.Popen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166973/sending-a-password-over-ssh-or-scp-with-subprocess-popen)

Comment: It does not, because I need to pragmatically get all the received text to analyze it. "user@192.168.254.1's password:" is a response provided by the remote target.