# Run shell commands in Python and enter password

Tags: python, subprocess, passwords

I need to copy a number of files from one PC to another using `scp`. Of course I can manually do it one by one, but since they are several files and each one can take up to one hour, I would like to automate this with a simple script. Normally I would simply do this:

```py
import subprocess

FILES_NAMES = [
    'file_1.raw',
    'file_2.raw',
]

for fname in FILES_NAMES:
    subprocess.run(['scp', f'user@pc:/path/to/files/{fname}', '.'])
```

but it keeps asking for the password each iteration.

Is it possible to do something like

```py
for fname in FILES_NAMES:
    subprocess.run(['scp', f'user@pc:/path/to/files/{fname}', '.'], propmt_password='hardcode_your_super_secure_password_here')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending a password over SSH or SCP with subprocess.Popen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166973/sending-a-password-over-ssh-or-scp-with-subprocess-popen)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this type of code like using sshpass and then give your password then file paths

```
import subprocess

FILES_NAMES = [
    'file_1.raw',
    'file_2.raw',
]

for fname in FILES_NAMES:
    subprocess.run(['sshpass', '-p', 'YOUR_PASSWORD', 'scp', f'user@pc:/path/to/files/{fname}', '.'])
```