# How to capture user input from Bash prompt with Python

Tags: python, mysql, bash, subprocess

I am running `mysql_secure_installation` which prompts the user for the root database password and asks the user to enter Yes or No to some other initial setup options. How would I capture the root password that the user enters?

I'm thinking something like :

```
capture = subprocess.Popen(['mysql_secure_installation'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
root_pwd = capture.communicate()
```

I'd like to also feed in default options to the other prompts. How can I do that?

Comment: can you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688441/how-can-i-set-a-users-password-in-linux-from-a-python-script?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

To intercept user input for a subprocess transparently, you could use [`pty.spawn()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pty.html):

```
import os
import pty

def read(fd):
    data = os.read(fd, 512)
    print('got input %r' % data)
    return data

pty.spawn('mysql_secure_installation', stdin_read=read)
```